# Numerical Conversion in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, boost, type-conversion, fixed-point

I need to convert a C/C++ double to a 64 bit two's complement, where the Radix point is at bit number 19 (inclusive).

This means that for the format I want to convert to

- 0x0000 0000 0010 0000 is the number 1
- 0xFFFF FFFF FFF0 0000 is the number -1
- 0x0000 0000 0000 0001 is 0.95 x 10^-6
- 0xFFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF is -0.95 x 10^-6

So far I've though about using the modf function from the C standard library, but that doesn't really cover my needs.  I've also looked at some type conversion classes in Boost, but I couldn't find the right solution there either.  Does anyone know of a library or easy way to do this conversion?  Maybe someone more familiar with Boost can point me in the right direction.

If [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision#IEEE_754_double_precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64) helps at all, here is some documentation of how doubles are stored.

Edit:

I have a follow up question, this is really for my own interest.  What is 'Radix'?  Here it's sort of like a decimal point.  But, the only other time I've heard the term Radix was when I was learning about the Discrete Fast Fourier Transform.  If I remember correctly, the Radix-II method is fast because there are fewer multiplies need to calculate the DFT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should give the results you want:

```
double d = someValue();
int64_t fixed_point = static_cast<int64_t>(d * (1024*1024));
```

Comment: I'd prefer to write "d * 0x100000" as it makes it more obvious where you are placing the radix. Personal taste though.

Comment: Good point. In real life I expect it will be used in more than one place, and should probably be a named constant. But for 44.20 bit fixed point, a hex literal is probably clearer than decimal.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply by 2^20 and then convert to the integer type you target (probably long long)