# Better way to convert decimal float into special hexadecimal notation

Tags: c++, floating-point, data-conversion

I have decimal numbers in the range between 0 and ~15.9 and want to convert them into a specific hexadecimal notation.
So the special notation goes like this:
There are 16 bits. The first 4 bits are for the pre-decimal-point position. The next 12 bits are for the decimal places.

`A * 16^0 + B * 16^{-1} + C * 16^{-2} + D * 16^{-3}`  
[image: Image of previous equation]

Here is how I am doing it now in C++ (I am "brute forcing" it. Just check how often 16 fits in A, then check how often 1/16 fits in B and so on):

```
uint16_t dec_to_special_hex(double x){
    uint16_t A, B, C, D;
    A = static_cast<uint16_t>(x);
    if (A > 15)
        return 65535;

    double remainder = x - A;    //get decimal places
    B = static_cast<uint16_t>(remainder * 16);
    remainder = remainder - B * (1 / 16);
    C = static_cast<uint16_t>(remainder * 16 * 16);
    remainder = remainder - C * (1 / (16 * 16));
    D = static_cast<uint16_t>(remainder * 16 * 16 * 16);
    remainder = remainder - D * (1 / (16 * 16 * 16));


    uint16_t temp, ret = A;
    ret = ret << 12;
    temp = B << 8;
    ret = ret | B;
    temp = C << 4;
    ret = ret | C;
    ret = ret | D;
    return ret;
}
```

I wounder if there is no better, more elegant way to do this. I am looking at the digits I am handling and it just feels like there must be more to it, but I could not find a better way yet.
Would be happy for your suggestions!

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, your "special hex notation" is a 4+12 bit fixpoint number. Just do `return x>=16 ? 65535 : static_cast<uint16_t>(x*(1<<12));` (probably also explicitly return 0 if `x<=0`, in case that ever happens)

Comment: wow :-) Thanks for the help. I did not realize that is a common notation. I will need to look up why this works exactly how it does but thank you! If you post it as an answer I will be happy to mark it as the correct one!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numerical Conversion in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179006/numerical-conversion-in-c-c) (Maybe someone finds a better duplicate ...)

Comment: Re “I have decimal numbers”: The input `x` is not a decimal number; it is a `double`. (A C++ implementation could use a decimal base for `double`, but no common implementations do; today’s all use binary.) People should avoid using “decimal” to mean “numbers with fractional parts” or “floating-point numbers” or “real numbers,” because this leads to the numerous questions we get about floating-point behavior where people are expecting it to behave like simple decimal arithmetic. It is not decimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wounder if there is no better, more elegant way to do this

*Elegant* is subjective, but:

One thing you can do is work with the bits directly. Check this [simple converter](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) to see how IEEE floating point numbers work (if you don't know already). Then look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53487778/struct-initialization-constructor-using-meta-programming) for a method to get the different groups of bits of a floating point number (the answer therein is for a `float` type, but the conversion to `double` is simple).

After you have the bits, All you need to do is shift the *mantissa*, depending on the *exponent*, and perform bit-wise `&` with different windows to get the bits for `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the links. I had worries about the accuracy but as you said, in the end I am only going to end up with a 16 bit number and precision is not my main concern.

Comment: Re “performing multiple arithmetic operations … reduces accuracy”: If the C++ implementation uses a binary-based format for `double`, as all common C++ implementations do, and the input `x` is not out of bounds for the `uint16_t`, then there will be no arithmetic errors in the code shown. The conversion to `uint16_t` truncates, producing on exact result in `A`. The subtraction of `A` produces an exact result by Sterbenz Lemma. The multiplication by 16 produces an exact result since it is a power of the floating-point base. And so on.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You're right. I didn't notice this. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just wish to truncate and not round, this can be done with:

```
uint16_t dec_to_special_hex(double x)
{
    return
        x < 0   ?     0 :
        16 <= x ? 65535 :
                  4096*x;
}
```